# iPhone drains the battery after disconnected from CarPlay

Tags: iphone, battery, car-integration

Occasionally, when I disconnect my phone from CarPlay, the iPhone will  drain the battery very quickly, but not always. In Battery Status I see no application running on the background, but the iPhone is quite hot, (although I did not touch it,) and in Control Centre, the menu is disabled ("Torch" is greyed, I can't turn it on/off.) Probably seems that something is using camera on background (I think, because Torch LED Flash is controlled by camera API.)

This state I see only after disconnecting from CarPlay.

The battery draining will stop after the iPhone restarts (full power OFF and ON cycle.)

Is there any way to detect what is draining the battery and how to prevent this from happening?

Using iPhone 7, problem occurs with iOS v12.2 - 12.3.1 (not tested with older versions) is connected to uconnect 4C 8.4, in Jeep 2018.

[image]

Comment: Did you make sure whichever navigation app you are using has registered you actually arrived? If it doesn't think you actually cleared your arrival point it will keep on trying to get you there & kill the battery pretty quickly.

Comment: No, no nav app was used.. only music app, same like in the morning and after disconnecting the battery draining was normal...

Comment: this is happening to me too, iphone 6... I read somewhere that turning off bluetooth could help, haven't tried it yet